# What is the song playing in My Hero Academia season 4 episode 13 at 5:40?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

As the title say, What song is playing in My Hero Academia episode 76 (season 4 episode 13) at 5:40?

Answer (score 0):

Might*u - I'll never let you go again.
https://youtu.be/HzE4LzutZGs

Comment: It's not this one

Comment: Yes, it is. The part that plays in the show is the bridge and chorus of this song.

Answer (score 0):

Is it this one? I made a cover of one from Episode 76 recently. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMTZRQ5pjWU